# codeigniter baseurl not working

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I am using the baseurl() in my application. ex: "http://www.edocapp.in"

This is working in case if we type domain name with "www" but not working if I use "only http".

Application is hosted on server.

Comment: How is it set in application/config/config.php? Try setting it like so: `$config['base_url'] = '';`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.edocapp.in';
```

this

Answer (score 0):

Base URL should have `/` in the last char:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.edocapp.in/';
```

anyway, you should check your DNS record in your server/hosting.

Does it have an alias (CNAME Records) to redirect `www.edocapp.in` to `edocapp.in` ?